# In formal writing, should you capitalise the word "colonies" referring to the thirteen colonies?

Tags: capitalization

In formal writing (MLA format essay) when should you capitalise the word colonies? I imagine the in the phrase "The Thirteen Colonies" it would be as that is a title, but I'm not sure if it is indeed correct. Also would it be capitalised in a sentence like one I'm writing, "This caused a rise in Christian influence in the Colonies" is that correct? Or should it be lowercase?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that in the sentence you quote that I would capitalise *colonies*.

There are instances, where, for example, if I was referring to them as an entity, I might use capitals - 'The Thirteen Colonies', or even 'The Colonies'.

e.g. *The population of Britain at the time was about 9 million, France 25 million and **The Thirteen Colonies** about 4 million.*

But there are other instances, where if, for example, I was just writing about British expansion generally I might say something like -

*...Britain's influence in North America following the Seven Years' war with France, was at its peak - across the whole of Canada and in **the thirteen colonies** of Virginia, Maryland, New York, Connecticut, New Jersey etc.*